# Flatten Dictionaries in Class Properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following models:

```
public class Input {
  public Dictionary<String, String> A { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<String, String> B { get; set; }
}

public class Output {
  public String Key { get; set; }
  public String A { get; set; }
  public String B { get; set; }
}
```

I got something as follows from a service:

```
List<Input> inputs = new List<Input> {
  new Input {
    A = new Dictionary<String, Int32> {
      { "EN", "Aen" },
      { "FR", "Afr" }
    },
    B = new Dictionary<String, Int32> {
      { "EN", "Ben" },
      { "FR", "Bfr" }
    }
  }
  // More inputs ...
}
```

I need to map this to a List as follows:

```
List<Output> outputs = new List<Output> {
  new Output { Key = "EN", A = "Aen", B = "Ben" },
  new Output { Key = "FR", A = "Afr", B = "Bfr" }
}
```

I was trying the following:

```
var outputs = inputs
  .Select(input => input.A.Select(a => 
     new Output { Key = a.Key, A = a.Value ... })
```

The problem is that to create an Output I need both values from A and B.

Comment: If key from A doenst exist in B default string is ok?

Comment: How can `Dictionary<String, Int32>` have `{ "EN", "Aen" }`? typo?

Comment: Does the `Dictionary` field in input have the same `Keys`? Do you wan't the output to list all the key from A or from B or from both?

Comment: @DragandDrop yes, they have the same keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) here:

```
var ouputs = input.A.Join(
    input.B,
    a => a.Key,
    b => b.Key,
    (a, b) => new Output { Key = a.Key, A = a.Value, B = b.Value }
);
```

From a performance point of view, this can be improved with more code, given you already have indexed data.

```
var ouputs = input.A.Map(a => {
    B b;
    if(input.B.TryGetValue(a.Key, out b)) {
        return { 
            Valid = true;
            Output = new Output { Key = a.Key, A = a.Value, B = b.Value }
        };
    } else {
        return { Valid = false, Output = null };
    }
}).Where(result => result.Valid)
  .Select(result => result.Output);
```

Both are strictly Inner Join. If you need data from A or B when there is no correspondance, this is going to be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `A` & `B` contains same `key` collections. So `input.A.Select` will iterate over `A` dictionary and it will give values for `Key` & `A` in `Output` class. For value of `B` we can directly fetch with `input.B[a.Key]` which will reduce further joins or complicated operations.

But it will provide `List<List<Output>>` so I've used `inputs.SelectMany` which will merge all values to single `List<Output>` list.

```
var outputs = inputs.SelectMany(input => input.A.Select(
              a => new Output 
                   { 
                       Key = a.Key, 
                       A = a.Value, 
                       B = input.B[a.Key]
                   });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information from you part I assume that A and B could have different keys.
In order to match the expected result I used SelectMany to flattern the list of list output.

```
var outputs = inputs
                  .SelectMany(input =>
                    input
                      .A.Keys               // all key from A
                      .Union(input.B.Keys)  // + all key from B without the duplicate
                      .Select(k =>
                        new Output
                         {
                            Key = k,
                            A = input.A.GetValueOrDefault(k),
                            B = input.B.GetValueOrDefault(k)
                         }
                       ) 
                   );
```

With this exention method,  :

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default) =>
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var ret) ? ret : defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your dictionaries **might have different keys**.

1st step - add a property to your `Input` class to return the distinct dictionary keys used by both dictionaries:

```
public class Input
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> A { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> B { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> aKeys = A?.Keys.ToList() ?? new List<string>();
            List<string> bKeys = B?.Keys.ToList() ?? new List<string>();

            return aKeys.Union(bKeys);
        }
    }
}
```

2nd step - create a method to convert an `Input` object to an `IEnumerable<Output>`:

```
private static IEnumerable<Output> CreateOutput(Input input)
{
    foreach (string key in input.Keys)
    {
        string aValue = null;
        string bValue = null;

        input.A?.TryGetValue(key, out aValue);
        input.B?.TryGetValue(key, out bValue);

        yield return new Output
        {
            A = aValue,
            B = bValue,
            Key = key
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, use `SelectMany` to flatten the lists into a single one:

```
List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>
{
    new Input
    {
        A = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"EN", "Aen"},
            {"FR", "Afr"},
            {"PT", "PT value"}, // key does not exist in B dictionary

        },
        B = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"EN", "Ben"},
            {"FR", "Bfr"},
            {"DE", "DE value"}, // key does not exist in A dictionary
        },
    }
};

List<Output> outputs = inputs.SelectMany(CreateOutput).ToList();
```

Output:

[image: Output list]

Comment: To handle `null` A and B, I would have made a getter that set them if they are null. this way I would have safe `A.Add()` on a null A. Add range and disting can be solved by a simple [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Or a default value the list, with `public List<Foo> Foos { get; } = new List<Foo>();`

Comment: @DragandDrop stupid me, I don't know how I forgot about `Union`, thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't specify it other way, I'm gonna assume that:

- input.A  may have same keys as input.B, but may have keys that are not in input.B.
- input.B  may have same keys as input.A, but may have keys that are not in input.A.
- both input.A and input.B are not null (but may be empty)

  ```
  public List<Output> Flatten(Input input)
  {
      var outputs = new List<Output>();
      foreach (var aKey in input.A.Keys)
      {
          //Check that input.B really has the key found in input.A
          outputs.Add(new Output{Key = aKey, A = input.A[aKey], B = input.B.ContainsKey(aKey)? input.B[aKey]:null});
      }
      //If input.B has some keys not in input.A 
      foreach (var bKey in input.B.Keys)
      {
          //Check that the bKey was not already inserted (didn't exist earlier)
          if (outputs.All(x => x.Key != bKey))
          {
              //A can be null.. it was not in the input.A
              outputs.Add(new Output {Key = bKey, A = null, B = input.B[bKey]});
          }
      }

      return outputs;
  }
  ```

I would redefine the List better as a dictionary with Key and a class that contains string A & B  so the second loop is faster.